# Generating all Unordered Combinations

Tags: permutation, combinatorics

I need to come up with an algorithm that generates all Unordered combinations of a set of Datapoints.

Let me give an example of say [0 1 2]

All the following are possible:

```
[(0,1,2)]
[(0,1) (2)] [(0,2) (1)] [(1,2) (0)]
[(0), (1), (2)]
```

For say [0 1 2 3] it gets alot more complicated

```
[(0,1,2,3)]
[(0,3) (1,2)] [(0,1) (3,2)] [(0,2) (3,1)] 
[(0,3,1) (2)] [(0,1,3) (2)] [(0,2,3) (1)]
[(0,3) (1) (2)] [(0,1) (3) (2)] [(0,2) (3) (1)]
[(1,2) (0) (3)] [(3,2) (1) (0)] [(3,1) (2) (0)]
[(0) (1) (2) (3)]
```

Something like this. I need a general solution to this problem for any size. I know it blows up to a larger number, but I need to generate this. How would I approach this problem?

Comment: Why is `[(0,1) (2)]` a possible output? This doesn't look like a "combination" in the normal sense of the word. Please explain your problem as specifically as possible.

Comment: Yes, youre right in that its not a combination. I need to devise an algorithm for this special case. We have a sensor that is trying to fire a laser beam onto N targets at once. We need to hit everyone of the targets, but sometimes we need multiple steps to hit all targets. so [(0,1) (2)] and [(0,1,2)] are valid solutions

Comment: OK, but then why is `[(0)]` also a possible output?

Comment: oh sorry i will edit the question it is suppose to be [(0) (1) (2)]. we are working in python so we have access to the itertools library if that helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all partitions of a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530128/how-to-find-all-partitions-of-a-set)

Comment: Interesting..i think it might. Its a shame they dont have a Python solution there

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646186/yielding-sub-combinations/) works for Python; [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59303187/how-to-iterate-through-all-partitions-of-a-list-with-a-condition-on-the-subsets) suggests that the `sympy` library has a function that works, too.

Comment: Great. Just a final question. Do you think a solution exists out there that doesn't use yield and generators? Eventually i need to port it to C++ that is why